# engine based on libGDX (for android)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

is there any engine based on [libGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/)? I found https://github.com/MattTuttle/Flume2D but it is not finished and not works well

thanks

Answer (score 8):

libgdx itself is not that bad once you get used to it. Especially if you're using scene2d.

Answer (score 2):

libGDX is an excellent way to build a game for android. Sure, it doesn't abstract away too much of the common complexities of making a game,but if you are learning game programming , you will benefit from that in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use physics in your game you can add the box2D engine to libgdx, they work great